# Never submitted suggested edit before, but shows one rejected?

Tags: support, bug, suggested-edits

I've never submitted a suggested edit on Meta.SO until a few minutes ago. [It was promptly approved…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/23058)

[image]

However, clicking *more* shows that I've had one accepted **and one rejected**…

[image]

Why? This was the first suggested edit I've submitted, as shown in the activity tab:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you never suggested edit to a content that got deleted later?

Comment: @Mołot I'm pretty confident that I haven't, but maybe…? Would that remove it from my activity?

Comment: @grgarside as far as I know, removed content is hidden on most lists, but still counts toward stats, so while I'm unsure, I dare to guess that yes, it would. Edit: and answer by insert clever xmas name confirms!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The rejected edit was on this post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208925/recent-badges-are-displaying-in-a-wrong-manner).

It was deleted by the user and this is why it is not showing in you reputation feed.

I found this in the data explorer. : https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/155917

Comment: Fair enough! :) Thanks

Comment: The link is to the deleted question, not to the edit suggestion. I suspect we can't see the suggestion anymore, it will give 404 even to 10K users same way timeline does. [Confirmed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8967).

Comment: @ShadowWizard Link name was misguiding. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting that it's not removed from the SuggestedEdits table, might be a bug, lol... I won't tell the devs if you don't tell. ;)